# How correct I executed the test case?

Tags: automated-testing, python, browser-automation, testcase, test-strategy

I'm new to Automation Testing.

So I have a simple test case - `Login with incorrect username and password`.

**Steps:**

1. Open the browser
2. Enter the URL “http://practice.automationtesting.in/”
3. Click on `My Account`
4. Enter incorrect username in `username` textbox
5. Enter incorrect password in `password` textbox.
6. Click on `login` button
7. Proper `error` must be displayed (i.e. Invalid username) and prompt to enter login again.

My logic is quite simple, if the provided `user/pass` are incorrect, I must receive an error message, and if I find this element on the page (by it's `XPath`), then the `user/pass` are incorrect indeed.

Here is my code:

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    baseURL = "http://practice.automationtesting.in/"
    username = "incorrect@email.com"
    password = "incorrect_password"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver.get(cls.baseURL)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_login(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-50']/a").click()
        lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
        lp.setUsername(self.username)
        lp.setPassword(self.password)
        lp.clickLogin()
        time.sleep(3)
        error = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-36']/div/div[1]/ul/li/strong")
        if error.is_displayed():
            print("Incorrect username/password, please provide another one.")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
```

Did I do something wrong? I'm sure there is another way to execute the `step #7`.

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally use an assert statement.

So
assert condition, "Custom message on failure of assert"

I'm not 100% on python but think the formatting would be:

```
assert error.is_displayed(),"Error - Expected incorrect password message to be displayed"
```